# Free satellite data availability for moon

Tags: data, satellite, moon

What are the satellite raster and vector data sets available for mapping the moon that can be freely downloaded? I need to know the availability and type of the data sets from which mineral mapping, feature mapping and other analysis of lunar surface can be performed.

Comment: Is there something specific you are looking for?  Raster? Vector? Landing sites? Please edit your question to indicate what it is you're after.

Comment: I am trying to map mineral composition, features etc.. possibly for a basin or a crater in moon which can be decided only by knowing the type of data sets and its free availability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps the following links might be useful:

- http://ode.rsl.wustl.edu/moon/coverage/ODE_Moon_shapefile.html
- https://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/pigwad/down/moon_dl.htm
- https://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/pigwad/down/moon_geology.htm

  The images below were taken from the data from the [last link](https://webgis.wr.usgs.gov/pigwad/down/moon_geology.htm) which gave some details on geology of the moon. But all datasets in the links are free:

  [image: Lunar data]

  [image: Lunar data]